# How to read and write at regular intervals?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to read a path every 5 minutes with Pyspark and then write what I read. How can I do this with code? I would be glad if you help.

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do to people you want to help you. Please write in normal capitalization.

Comment: Sleep 5 minutes